# Algorithm: Find the union matrix, given the two unified,sorted matrices

Tags: algorithm, sorting, matrix, time-complexity, union

Given two sorted matrices A and B with n different elements each, which is the algorithm that, in O(logn) time, can find the matrix C produced by their union?

```
A ∪ B = C
```

Comment: What is a union? Is it like a set union operator? Anyway, I highly doubt one can do it in `O(log n)` because we at least need to print the output and read the input, which is `O(n)` (by the way, what `n` is?).

Comment: @kraskevich n is the amount of the different elements of the two matrices.

Comment: @Zap union without duplicates?

Comment: @maraca I suppose so, it's not defined by the question Im given. If there would be dublicates, it wouldn't be a union as much as a merging.

Comment: @Zap I don't think it is possible unless the numbers in  both arrays are not only sorted and unique but also contiguous integers.

Comment: "@maraca I'm trying to figure out more information on the question since as it is at the moment, it can't be solved. I will keep you updated once I receive additional info.

Comment: @Zap yes I just figured out that if the arrays are contiguous and we can split and concat in O(1) then the solution would be O(1) too, seems to be too restrictive.

Comment: @maraca i'm concerned about how it has to be O(logn)... It could be something simpler than that? I doubt it. But then again, how does one handle 2dimensional matrices quickly?

Comment: I would call it cheating, but maybe the solution is something like this: A union of m arrays of size n is represented as m * n array, so adding an element to the union can be done in O(1) and to see if an element is present in the union we need O(m * logn), since m is a constant 2, it could be regarded as O(logn). For matrices instead of arrays it would be 3d but same logic.

Comment: @Zap it can be simpler O(1) if the arrays are continguous, let's say A[0] is smaller than B[0] (otherwise swap), then you can compare A[n-1] to B[0], if A[n-1] is smaller return concatention of A and B. Otherwise you can use the fact that the array is contiguous and calculate how many elements are overlapping by subtracting B[0] from A[n-1] (add 1) and then split array A by this index, take the lower part and concatenate with B.

Comment: @maraca supposing A,B are arrays and note matrices, that is. How could we turn this into a 2D algorithm? That's my main problem.